# VB.net and DATABASE. i Kept getting an record without an Entry Level record (IN)

Tags: vb.net

i kept getting an record without an Entry Level record (IN) that supposably will have an IN(database record) instead of NOTHING... However after it was scanned after another try only when IN is found in the database.... Overall I will just make an details but empty entry_record which is incomplete

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8YYS.png)

```
 Private Sub TextBox7_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox7.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then

        'Dim idnum = Val(TextBox7.Text
        Dim statu As String = ""
        Dim idnum = (TextBox7.Text)
        Dim record As String = ""

            TextBox2.Text = ""
            TextBox3.Text = ""
            TextBox4.Text = ""

            ConnectToDB()
        sql = "select * from rfidmaintest.student_details_dub where f9  = '" & idnum & "'"
            cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, cn)
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

            While dr.Read

                TextBox2.Text = (dr("f2"))
                TextBox3.Text = (dr("f9"))
                TextBox4.Text = (dr("f4"))
                TextBox5.Text = (dr("f14"))
                TextBox6.Text = (dr("f3"))
            TextBox7.Clear()

        End While
        dr.Close()
        cn.Close()

        'ANOTHER FETCH
        ConnectToDB()
        sql = "select * from rfidmaintest.monitoring where id_num  = '" & idnum & "'"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, cn)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        While dr.Read

            If (dr("entry_record")) = "IN" Then
                record = "OUT"
            ElseIf (dr("entry_record")) = "OUT" Then
                record = "IN"
            ElseIf (dr("entry_record")) = String.Empty Then
                record = "IN"
            End If
            status.Text = (record)



        End While
        dr.Close()
        cn.Close()


        ConnectToDB()
        sql = "insert into monitoring (id_num, fname, lname, status, entry_record, floor_level, date) VALUES (@num, @name, @lname, @stat, @record, @lev,@date)"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, cn)


        With cmd

            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@num", idnum)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TextBox2.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", TextBox6.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@stat", TextBox5.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@lev", levellock.sharevalue)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@record", status.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", Date.Now)

            .ExecuteReader()
        End With



        MsgBox("Details has been saved!", vbInformation, "Saved")


        cmd = Nothing
        dr.Close()
        cn.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't follow your explanation at all. Can you please elaborate? There's obviously there's a language barrier here but I think you'll need to try harder. Maybe others will understand it better.

Comment: @jmcilhinney im trying to make an handsfree rfid attendance... to import an data from another table if there is no existing record it will put an IN and if there is then it is OUT... but after I scann I kept getting an empty tablename(entry_record) instead of IN

Comment: @jmcilhinney it's done sir i;ve made my constant

Answer (score 0):

ConnectToDB()
sql = "select * from rfidmaintest.student_details_dub where f9  = '" & idnum & "'"
cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, cn)
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

```
        While dr.Read

            TextBox2.Text = (dr("f2"))
            TextBox3.Text = (dr("f9"))
            TextBox4.Text = (dr("f4"))
            TextBox5.Text = (dr("f14"))
            TextBox6.Text = (dr("f3"))
            TextBox7.Clear()
            status.Text = "IN"

        End While
        dr.Close()
        cn.Close()

        'ANOTHER FETCH
        ConnectToDB()
        sql = "select * from rfidmaintest.monitoring where id_num  = '" & idnum & "'"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, cn)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        While dr.Read

            'If status.Text = "IN" Then
            'record = "OUT"
            '   ElseIf status.Text = "OUT" Then
            '   record = "IN"
            '   ElseIf status.Text = String.Empty Then
            '    record = "IN"
            '     End If
            'status.Text = (record)


            If (dr("entry_record")) = "IN" Then
                record = "OUT"
            ElseIf (dr("entry_record")) = "OUT" Then
                record = "IN"
            ElseIf (dr("entry_record")) = String.Empty Then
                record = "IN"
            End If
            status.Text = (record)



        End While
        dr.Close()
        cn.Close()
```

stated the STATUS as IN

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).